# Type errors when using same name

Tags: ocaml

I have 3 files:

1) `cpf0.ml`

```
type string = char list
type url = string
type var = string
type name = string
type symbol =
| Symbol_name of name
```

2) `problem.ml:`

```
type symbol =
  | Ident of string
```

3) `test.ml`

```
open Problem;;
open Cpf0;;

let symbol b = function
  | Symbol_name n -> Ident n
```

When I combine `test.ml`: `ocamlc -c test.ml`.
I received an error:

*This expression has type Cpf0.name = char list
 but an expression was expected of type string*

Could you please help me to correct it? Thank you very much

**EDIT**: Thank you for your answer. I want to explain more about these 3 files:
Because I am working with extraction in Coq to Ocaml type: `cpf0.ml` is generated from 
`cpf.v` :

```
 Require Import String.
 Definition string := string.
 Definition name := string.
 Inductive symbol := 
  | Symbol_name : name -> symbol.
```

The code `extraction.v`:

```
Set Extraction Optimize.
Extraction Language Ocaml.
Require ExtrOcamlBasic ExtrOcamlString.
Extraction Blacklist cpf list.
```

where [ExtrOcamlString](http://coq.inria.fr/V8.3/stdlib/Coq.extraction.ExtrOcamlString.html)

I opened: `open Cpf0;;` in `problem.ml`, and I got a new problem because in `problem.ml` they have another definition for type `string`

***This expression has type Cpf0.string = char list
       but an expression was expected of type Util.StrSet.elt = string***

Here is a definition in `util.ml` defined type string:

```
module Str = struct type t = string end;;
module StrOrd = Ord.Make (Str);;
module StrSet = Set.Make (StrOrd);;
module StrMap = Map.Make (StrOrd);;

let set_add_chk x s =
  if StrSet.mem x s then failwith (x ^ " already declared")
  else StrSet.add x s;;
```

I was trying to change `t = string` to `t = char list`, but if I do that I have to change a lot of function it depend on (for example: `set_add_chk` above). Could you please give me a good idea? how I would do in this case.

**EDIT 2**: I am sorry to edit this question many times. After follow the answer, I fixed the file problem.ml

```
type symbol =
  | Ident of Cpf0.string
```

In `problem.ml` they have another definition like this. And the type one again does not accepted.

```
module SymbSet = Set.Make (SymbOrd);;
let rec ident_of_symbol = function
  | Ident s -> s

let idents_of_symbols s =
  SymbSet.fold (fun f s -> StrSet.add (ident_of_symbol f) s) s StrSet.empty;;
```

**This expression has type Cpf0.string = char list but an expression was expected of type Util.StrSet.elt = string**

Comment: If you have other problems, you should ask new questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to open module Cpf0 in problem.ml because the type string in modules Cfp0 and Problem is not the same.

problem.ml:

```
open Cpf0
type symbol =
  | Ident of string
```

or better, don't open the module and prefix the type string like this:

```
type symbol =
  | Ident of Cpf0.string
```

Comment: I'd add that naming something `string` may cause more confusion than clarity you'd gain.

Comment: It's usually best you don't open the modules at all; thus you'd have, `Cpf0.Symbol_name`.