# Idea working in types

Tags: ocaml

Please see details in [My previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026597/type-errors-when-using-same-name)

```
1) cpf0.ml:
type string = char list
type name = string
type symbol =
| Symbol_name of name

2) problem.ml:

type symbol =
  | Ident of Cpf0.string
```

In this `problem.ml` it has two definitions for type `string`, and surely it's giving me an error, but is it posible that I can make them have a same type? I need an idea.

```
module Str = struct type t = string end;;
module StrOrd = Ord.Make (Str);;
module StrSet = Set.Make (StrOrd);;
module StrMap = Map.Make (StrOrd);;

module SymbSet = Set.Make (SymbOrd);;
let rec ident_of_symbol = function
  | Ident s -> s

let idents_of_symbols s =
  SymbSet.fold (fun f s -> StrSet.add (ident_of_symbol f) s) s StrSet.empty;;
```

**This expression has type Cpf0.string = char list but an expression was expected of type Util.StrSet.elt = string**

Answer (score 2):

You can use the name "string" for different types in different modules if you like, though (as Basile Starynkevitch points out) it's confusing.  It would be better to pick a different name.  If you really need to reuse the name, you can specify the module every time.  If you don't specify a module, you'll get the predefined meaning (or the meaning from the innermost opened module).

It seems to me the problem in your quoted code is that this line:

```
module Str = struct type t = string end;;
```

doesn't specify a module name for string, so it refers to the predefined `string`.  It seems possible you wanted to say:

```
module Str = struct type t = Cpf0.string end;;
```

It's hard to tell, however.  There's not enough context for me to really understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

`string` is a predefined type in Ocaml (ie in the `Pervasives` module); it is e.g. the type of string literal constants like `"this string"`. Use some other name (otherwise you, and any one reading your code, will be very confused)

Comment: Could you please me more explanation? Thank you very much.